# Django-- Multiple Models with Multiple Databases

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on file transformation workflows and the whole project is based on Django.
How the project works is , each django app is a new workflow , and once a files comes in it will invoke the workflows one after the another. My question is how to connect multiple databases from single model.py. Below is what I am trying to achieve

The Main Project Structure

```
Kappa
  |--Kappa
  |--FileTransformSAP
  |--FileTransformARIBA
  |--FileTransformWorkday
  .....
  .....
```

Each of the Apps have a similar Structure listed below.

```
FileTransformSAP
   |--__init__.py
   |--admin.py
   |--apps.py
   |--models.py
   |--tests.py
   |--views.py
```

I have three Databases Namely, Landing, Staging and Final

What I am trying to achieve is the model.py file will have three different classes namely, _landing, _staging and _final and this three classes should be able to interact with three different databases and mentioned above.

I am already using routers.py to segregate databases for auth and application, but I am getting stuck when single model.py containing various model class needs to be applied to different databases

Sample Model.py

```
class <anything>_landing(models.Model):
    definition
 
    class Meta:
        app_label = '<anything>_landing'

class <anything>_staging(models.Model):
    definition
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = '<anything>_staging'

class <anything>_final(models.Model):
    definition
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = '<anything>_final'
```

Along with this created the following routes.py

```
class LandingRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'<anything>_landing'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "landing"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "landing"
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == "landing"
        return None

class StagingRouter:

    route_app_labels = {'<anything>_staging'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "staging"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "staging"
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == "staging"
        return None
```

Similary Router for Final is also created

And here is the snippet from settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
   'default':{},
   'landing': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'NAME': 'landing',
       'USER': 'postgres',
       'PASSWORD': 'admin',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   },
   'staging': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'NAME': 'staging',
       'USER': 'postgres',
       'PASSWORD': 'admin',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   },
   'final': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'NAME': 'final',
       'USER': 'postgres',
       'PASSWORD': 'admin',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```

But this is not generating any kind of migrations.
Can any one tell what approach I need to take for the situation explained